# JQuery - if screen size is less than 767 and an element is empty

Tags: jquery, html

I want to write jquery code to detect screen size is less than 767px and an element is empty, in this case a span.

```
 if ( ($(window).width() <= 767) && ($.trim($(".btm").html())=='' ) ){

            $('.element').show();
        } else {

            $('.element').hide();
        }

<span class="btm"> </span>
```

this code isn't working, anyone see why it wouldn't? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's because the DOM isn't ready when you execute this code. `$(".btm")` can't be found. Use

```
$(function() { 
     your code here will be executed when the page is ready
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution dystroy offered may be the reason you're encountering an issue. Another thing to be cognisant of is the order that you call your JS files and your Javascript.

For example, this will **NOT** work:

```
<body>

<script>
if ( ($(window).width() <= 767) && ($.trim($(".btm").html())=='') ){
    $('.element').show();
} else {
    $('.element').hide();
}
</script>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<span class="btm"> </span>

</body>
```

The JavaScript used to check if the window less than or equal to 767 pixels wide and if the `.btm` span element is empty uses jQuery! So you need to be sure that you're calling jQuery before executing the JavaScript like so:

```
<body>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
if ( ($(window).width() <= 767) && ($.trim($(".btm").html())=='') ){
    $('.element').show();
} else {
    $('.element').hide();
}
</script>

<span class="btm"> </span>

</body>
```